# Why does cropping behave like that?

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick, dragonfly-gem

I've got an image with dimensions `126x75`:

```
(rdb:1) p image.width
126
(rdb:1) p image.height
57
```

Now I want to crop it down to `50x50`, beginning at the north west (top left corner). So I tried that (which should be similar to IMs command line geometry parameter `50x50+0+0`):

```
image2 = image.process(:crop, :width => 50, :height => 50, :x => 0, :y => 0)
```

But the result is somewhat surprising to me:

```
(rdb:1) p image2.width
24
(rdb:1) p image2.height
16
```

Why does it happen like that? What's the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the image you're using has existing page geometry that is causing your (0,0) location to be offset. You can tell IM to repage the image to remove the existing page geometry so that (0,0) is the "true" (0,0). Check the IM documenation: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_page

Comment: That's the right idea, thanks! But only the crop method seems to have an optional parameter to repage. There are many helper functions using the crop function which don't accept that parameter. Workaround: `image.crop!(0, 0, image_width, image_height, true)` before each of those methods. Not perfect but does the job.